# App won't start with Xamarin iOS Facebook SDK

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I have no idea what's going wrong. I just want to integrate the [Facebook iOS SDK from Xamarin](https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookios) and call the 'ActivateApp' Event, so that I can see how many users opened the app from the Facebook-App with an ad from me.

I created a blank Xamarin.Forms app, added the component from the component store and modified my AppDelegate class:

```cs
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    Settings.AppID = "<myFacebookId>";

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    LoadApplication(new App());

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

I am aware that I need to update the Info.plist file also and do some more stuff. But the special here is, with above steps the app won't start on my device (Configuration: Debug | iPhone, Linker disabled, sdk Version 9.2, deployment target 7.1) but on my smulator it works fine.

On the device, the splashscreen just shows for half a second, then it crashs without any Feedback.

My brain explodes next time. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the Xamarin-support, I have a solution for my problem.

Answer from the Support:

> It looks like the issue you are hitting is related to App Transport
>   Security, so you’ll need to whitelist a couple things by editing your
>   plist to fix the crash on device. You can read more about how to do
>   this in the Facebook developer guide, “[Preparing Your Apps for iOS
>   9](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9)”:
>
> Basically, what you’ll do is this:
>
> 1. Double-click info.plist and go to Source tab
> 2. Add Custom Property “LSApplicationQueriesSchemes”, type “Array”
> 3. Add Strings with the following values: fbapi, fb-messenger-api, fbauth2, fbshareextension

It’s a little bit akward… As I wrote you in my question, I am aware that there are more things to do (like editing the plist-file). But unfortunately, I obviously put the wrong values in my plist-file.